# SNMP through NAT when server has two IP addresses

Tags: nat, snmp

We have an SNMP client talking to an SNMP agent through NAT. That works most of the time. We send an SNMP request e.g. from 1.2.3.4:12345 to 10.0.0.1:161 and get a reply from 10.0.0.1:161 to 1.2.3.4:12345.

However, some agents have multiple IP addresses, and for these when for such a server an SNMP request from 1.2.3.4:12345 to 10.0.0.1:161 we may get a reply from  a totally different IP address, e.g. from 10.0.1.1:161 to 1.2.3.4:161. I'm presuming this is because SNMP uses UDP and therefore doesn't have a connect, and the agent's default gateway uses 10.0.1.1:161.

This works fine on a "real" directly-connected client without NAT, but when NAT is involved the client's response is not sent through NAT to the client.

We're using standard `iptables` NAT.

- Is there any way to get `iptables` to only look at port numbers for UDP NAT so it'll send these replies from other IP addresses through?
- Are there better NAT implementations for our purposes that we haven't tried?

Changing the IP address we ask is unfortunately not an option...

Comment: Have you got double NAT somewhere? Can you get rid of it?

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact, there is a double NAT. How does that contribute to the problem though? Wouldn't this occur with a single NAT too?